# sql except - one column not included

Tags: sql

I have two the same tables (one is a copy of another but records where inserted at different time). Let's say they look like that (but with like 40 columns instead of 3 like in my example):

Table 1

```
a   b    time
--------------
1   5    13:00
2   6    13:01
3   7    13:02
```

Table 2

```
a   b    time
---------------
1   5    15:00
2   6    15:01
3   7    15:02
```

I would like to compare them using a simple EXCEPT like

```
SELECT * FROM Table 1
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM Table 2
```

I was trying with WHERE clause but it didn't work. How to do EXCEPT statement without a column time? because for me it's totally fine when in the time column I have different values. I am comparing them now using "not exists" but I would prefer some easier way to do it.

Comment: Don't use `select *`

Comment: but the thing is that I want to compare 40 columns except one so I thought it will be easier to do this with select * than writing every 39 columns in a select statement

Comment: I pretty sure writing out those 39 columns would have taken less time then typing in the question here. Typically SQL GUI client can help you with auto-completion so you don't have to type all those names manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution is that you need to list all the columns:

```
select a, b, c, . . .
from table1
except
select a, b, c, . . .
from table2;
```

You can generate the column list using system tables.  You don't specify your database, but something like:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'table1' and column_name <> 'time'
order by ordinal_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is structure use  EXCEPT

```
    SELECT column1 [, column2 ]
    FROM table1 [, table2 ]
    [WHERE condition]

   EXCEPT

  SELECT column1 [, column2 ]
  FROM table1 [, table2 ]
  [WHERE condition]
```

so :

```
      SELECT a,b FROM Table 1
      EXCEPT 
     SELECT a,b FROM Table 2
```